# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 relaying denied with Java Mail API

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have two services running(with same user) on a server which uses same code to send mail to a particular address. The code uses Java mail API(javax.mail.*) to send this mail. The sender,receiver and other configuration is exactly same in both the case. The issue is I get com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 relaying denied error from one service while other service is able to send mail succesfully. What could be the issue and is there a particular Configuration at receiver side which needs to be corrected.

Comment: Is your application authenticating to your mail server in both cases?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Are you using the same mail server in both cases?

Comment: Hi Bill, As I said all configuration is same for both services so authentication(mail.smtp.ssl.trust) and mail server are same in both the cases.

Comment: Can you post the debug output for each case?